# Why does the app not crash upon implementation of Firebase Crashlytics?

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, crashlytics

I am trying to integrate firebase crashlytics in my flutter app. For this, I am using the following library.

https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_crashlytics

Currently, I am testing for iOS and I have followed the iOS integration steps as mentioned in the documentation (Step 1 - 4, I am using XCode 11.3.1). And, in the main function I have the following line.

```
FlutterError.onError = Crashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError;
```

To test the crashes, I have added an index out of bounds scenario in my code as:

```
List<String> courseBackground = [
'courseBackground0.png',
'courseBackground1.png',
'courseBackground2.png'
];

Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/images/' + courseBackground[3]),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
    ),
    child: Text('Hello'),
)
```

When testing the release version of the app, the log shows error message as:

```
Flutter error caught by Crashlytics plugin:
.
.
Error reported to Crashlytics
```

However, the app does not crash.

And in the console, the Crashlytics dashboard looks like:

[image]

So everything is being recorded under non-fatals. But if I remove Crashlytics and run the app, then the app does crash. So I am confused why the app is not crashing after implementing Crashlytics.

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is related to using IDEs with widget inspector. Widget inspector sets the `FlutterError.onError` handler away from what is set in main.dart. So once the widget inspector is running the Crashlytics plugin will never handler errors.

This should only be an issue for apps in debug mode while widget inspector is running. Release mode apps should work as expected since there is no widget inspector; also running the app from the terminal with flutter run should also work as expected since there is no widget inspector involved in that case. When using flutter run be sure to use flutter clean since sometimes the inspector may still be attached to the app.